# Difference between related and relevant

Tags: meaning

I wants to know Difference between related and relevant

Example:

1. it's related to my topic
2. it's relevant to my topic

Comment: Please edit your question to explain why the different dictionary definitions are still confusing to you?  Otherwise the question may be closed for lack of detail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Related means that there is some topical connection between two or more things. Relevant means that one thing is meaningfully related to another, often in a practical sense for a given context.

So, for example, you could say that math.stackexchange is related to ell.stackexchange (in that they're both StackExchange sites), but also that the one is probably not relevant to the other in terms of content (the topics covered by each site probably don't overlap much).

Comment: Good example, although it's worth noting that _related_ has broader usages. For example, we could say that ELL and GrammarGirl both have related content, even though they are not related websites.